# Local storage not refreshing on my chrome when JavaScript load, unless i refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage

when I call the collectform callback function inside the formButton listener, I get everything good except that I don't see the object data in the chrome local storage immediately unless i refresh the local storage manually.

```js
 function collectFormData(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let noteTitle = tiTxt.value
        let noteContent = pTxt.value
        let date = new Date()
        const currTime = (date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', hour12: true }));
       
        let noteObj = {
            noteTitle,
            noteContent,
            loc,
            currTime
        }
        if (!noteTitle && !noteContent === true) {
            alert('Add note title and content');
        } else {
            allNotes.push(noteObj)
            wlocalStorage.setItem('noteData', JSON.stringify(allNotes));
            (function () {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('noteData'));
            })() 
            let payload = noteObj;
            payloadArray.push(payload)
            // xhr object listen on the server and send data to the server
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/dash');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payloadArray))
            function showData() {

                let htmlNote = `                   
                <div class="new-content">
                    <div class="new_content-child">
                    <div class="parent_h2-span">
                    <h2 class="content-h2">${noteTitle}</h2>
                    <span>${currTime}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="parent_content-p">
                    <p class="content-p">${noteContent}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="locality-container">
                    <p class="locality-p">${loc}</p>
                    <span class="edit-con">
                    <i class="edit-fa fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="false"></i>
                    
                    </span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    `
                contentContainer[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', htmlNote)
            }
            showData()
            tiTxt.value = pTxt.value = '';
        }
    }
    try {
        formButton.addEventListener('click', collectFormData)
    }
```

Comment: *"that I don't see the object data in the chrome local storage immediately"* What do you mean by that sentence? That the view in the developer tools doesn't refresh automatically? Well, chrome doesn't do that, and that's what the little refreh icon on the top left is there for ...

Comment: i saw tutorials of it happening immediately after the script runs,  so i thought that was the reason why when i use getItem.localStorage my html file doesn't persist, i dont see anything on the screen after refresh the page

Comment: I had to change tabs in the DevTools, e.g. change from Application Tab to Network Tab, and the local storage value updates visually

Comment: While this was asked before [a later duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73076406/20170164), I think the later one is slightly better in terms of detail and clarity.