# Chrome devtool localstorage info not update in time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, local-storage, devtools

Chrome version: 103.0.5060.134 (arm64)

**Before:**
LocalStorage and SessionStorage were updated in real time following the page js operation,

**Now:**
Need to switch devtools tab or click devtools left-top refresh button manually to check the latest value.

Question:

1. Is this the latest design of Chrome devtool?
2. Is there a setting to revert to in-time updates?

Comment: I also noticed that. Chrome 103.0.5060.53

Comment: Same here. Latest Chrome 103.0.5060.134 (Officiële build) (x86_64). [More people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066905/local-storage-not-refreshing-on-my-chrome-when-javascript-load-unless-i-refresh) noticed this.

Comment: Chrome 104.0.5112.101 Same here

Comment: Version 109.0.5414.119 (Official Build) (arm64) Same here

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in v103 and v104. Here's its [chromium bug tracker ticket (1354509)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1354509). The issue is resolved by v105.0.5195.52 (possibly also earlier v105 patches, but not confirmed in the bug tracker ticket).

It may have been related to [this other bug (1339280)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1339280), which has also been fixed in v105.